# How to center a div around another element?

Tags: css, html, margin, tumblr

I'm trying to edit a tumblr theme to make my posts centered inside of an image (the image is in a div) I've tried giving the posts and div the same margin in CSS but I can't seem to get the image inside the div to center correctly on the page. I want the posts to be perfectly centered horizontally inside the image even when the browser window is resized. Anybody know how i can do this? Is there an easier way than having the image in a div? here is a link to my code

http://pastebin.com/x6MP6EYQ

Comment: It's hard to glean much from that code. Post a working example on jsFiddle. It's probably better to set the image as a background, and perhaps center the posts with `margin: 0 auto;`, but I'd rather see a real example.

Comment: can you show us the template you are working on, with a plain text, it's hard to debug. `text-align:center` **might** work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would recommend using image as a background image. Would be easy to handle it as it will not affect other things inside a div.

Second, if you were to use image you would position it absolutely which mean main div should be positioned relatively. Then once image has been positioned i.e. `top:0; left:0;` put `z-index:-100;` so that way it will be always behind.

To make div always be centered both horizontally, vertically and in both directions. See my example. Here:

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/TfLTR/

Answer (score 0):

```
try style=aligen:center;
```

just you can manage by style sheet tag like padding and  margin also .